# How to access value for Firebase cloud function database onCreate trigger

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

I create a function for send email after onCreate fired but got the problem 
after trying access value

```
exports.sendEmailConfirmation = functions.database
.ref('/contact')
.onCreate(async (snapshot, context) => {
  const val = snapshot.val();
  console.log(val);
  const mailOptions = {
  from: val.name,
  to: 'kris@gmail.com',
  title: val.message,
};

try {
  await mailTransport.sendMail(mailOptions);
  console.log(`New ${val.message ? '' : 'un'} message sent to:`, val.email);
} catch (error) {
  console.error('There was an error while sending the email:', error);
}
return null; 
});
```

got undefined

**New un message sent to: undefined**

then try to console seem have a key that want to reference but is random

```
{ '-LuFhQVjr-T7UFYioi-d': 
 { email: 'Kris@gmail.com',
 message: 'Hello cloud function',
 name: 'Kris' 
 } 
}
```

try to use spread again but got more problem function doesnt fired

how I access this?

Comment: On Stack Overflow, please do not show pictures of text.  It's better to copy the text into the question so it's easier to read and search.

Comment: That `new un message sent to: undefined` seems to come from somewhere else, since your code only logs `snapshot.val()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you're trying to trigger a function when a new node is created **under** `/contact`. In that case, you want to include a placeholder for the path of the new child node in your declaration:

```
exports.sendEmailConfirmation = functions.database
.ref('/contact/{pushid}')
.onCreate(async (snapshot, context) => {
  const val = snapshot.val();
  console.log(val);
  const mailOptions = {
    from: val.name,
    to: 'rferfe@gmail.com',
    title: val.message,
  };
  ...
```